# Complex SQL Query/Update

Tags: mysql

I have a complex mysql query/update. I would like advice on how to approach this.

I will break down into logical steps first.

1. Select all id's from `Table_A` where `a`=`b`;

   - SELECT `Table_A`.`Table_A_id` FROM `Table_A` WHERE `connected`='true';
2. For all `Table_A_id` (from query in 1), find all users that have a matching `Table_A_id`.
3. For all those users, look into userdetails table and copy `userdetails`.`contact_email` to `users`.`email`.

Will add table description a bit later

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: I can make the query to get all the ids, but how do I then continue to step 2, then step 3?

Comment: SELECT `partners`.`partner_id` FROM `partners`
WHERE `connected`='true'; (partners is Table_A in my question

Comment: Please include the above SQL in your question. Also, please describe all the tables that are involved in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, if I have understood correctly

```
UPDATE users a 
    JOIN Table_A c ON c.Table_A_id = a.Table_A_id 
    JOIN userdetails b ON a.Table_A_id = b.Table_A_id 
SET a.email = b.contact_email;
WHERE c.a = b;
```

Comment: Can I change the second to be JOIN userdetails b ON a.user_id = b.user_id, since the Table_A_id is only present in users table, not the userdetails table

Comment: @MikeL, yes definitely you can. that's an example shown, do change it per your need.